# Get rows from dataframe with multicolumn conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It will be easy to show what I want then explain it. Consider the following dataframe:

```
dr = {'mac':[1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2], 's': ['aa', 'aa', 'c', 'd', 'ee', 'f']}
d = pd.DataFrame(data=dr)
```

Desiable output is:

```
    mac     s
0   1      aa 
4   1      ee
```

I need to find all 'mac' for which there are both 'aa' and 'ee' values. In example about it is true for mac = 1. For mac = 3 it is false because there is 'aa' value but not 'ee'.

Answer (score 7):

IIUC `filter` with `isin`

```
out=d.groupby('mac').filter(lambda x : pd.Series(['aa','ee']).isin(x['s']).all())
Out[62]: 
   mac   s
0    1  aa
4    1  ee
```